# Splitting stacked text string

Tags: excel

I have a data set where the two values are stacked on top of each other in the cells. I would like to split the text string, and then re-connect using a modifier.

Have:

```
        __A__  __B__
    1|  30521  56450
        22.95  22.83
        _____  _____
    2|  52808  98082
        39.71  39.67
```

Want:

```
    A     B
1| 30521  22.95 
2| 56450  22.83
3| 52808  39.71
4| 98082  39.67
```

Here is the formula I used:

```
=RIGHT(Data!B4,FIND(" ",Data!B4)-1)
```

My fear is that there isn't actually a space between the two values in each cell. Rather they have been stacked. Is there a symbol I should be searching for in the `FIND` statement?

EDIT: formula below works except in instances where the top value is larger. Still inserting blank character.(no, it is not a column width issue).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one for bottom value:

```
=RIGHT(Data!B4,FIND(CHAR(10),Data!B4)-1)
```

and for top value:

```
=LEFT(Data!B4,FIND(CHAR(10),Data!B4)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. What does the CHAR(10) do, though?

Comment: your values are delimited with special character called "Line feed" and this character has ASCII code `10`. `CHAR(10)` just returns character using it's code. Look here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: This largely works, except for instances where the bottom value is larger. I included an edit to the original to show what I mean.

Comment: Where the top value has more than 5 characters, a blank is inserted after the first parenthesis. So I have to manually delete there, even though the formula is the exact same. Do I need to change the CHAR value?